# Can't see shading in 3d view

Tags: 3d-view

Everything shows up in render. (using blender 2.70a)

[image: Render]

But in 3d view only the mesh shows, switching between wireframe & solid only shows wireframe (or the option we get to change with "Z" key)

with wireframe viewport toggled
[image: with wireframe]

with solid viewport toggled
[image: with solid]

Only changing "maximum draw type" to solid or textured shows white shading but not the orange color I gave in materials.

[image]

New cubes show shading though.

Comment: What is the question? I'm not sure I understand.. Changing the maximum draw type to textured and switching to textured view should work

Comment: blenderLearner.  I think you should edit out the two wireframe pictures in the middle.  They don't help to make your point and are misleading because they are irrelevant to your point but seem to have some point just because they are there.

Comment: @MarcClintDion I think that is the point.. Or it might be, currently it's kindof vague..

Comment: New to English or new to the world I suppose.  Anyways, I like Stackers answer, I never use that mode and totally forgot about it.

Comment: The point of the 2 mid images is that the viewport is toggled to be in wireframe & solid respectively, but blender only shows the wireframe.
And the last image give me a solid view but I don't see the orange color given.

Comment: @blenderLearner Set the maximum draw type to textured and the viewport mode to textured or material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you expected the solid or textured mode not to be rendered partially transparent, This is because you're in *Edit Mode* and have toggled the *Limit selection to visible* option:

[image]

Comment: This helped with transparency but I still can't get to see the orange color I have given to it.

Comment: @blenderLearner could you upload your .blend at http://www.pasteall.org/blend/ ?

Comment: Actually I started again from scratch and saved over the old file. Your answer did solve that transparency.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the several other wonderful answers given.  You can also change the *viewport color* at the bottom of the *materials* panel of the *properties* editor.  This does not in any way affect the rendering of the object it will only color the object in *solid view* mode.

Answer (score 1):

By default the *Maximum draw type* is set to *textured*.
This is a per object setting, so new objects will have this set to textured.

This setting defines the maximum draw type of  the object, in the order of

1. *Bounds*. Draws the object's bounding box.

   With *maximum draw type* set to *bounds*, the object will only ever be drawn as a bounding box.
2. *Wire*. Draws the object's edges as a wireframe.

   With *maximum draw type* set to *wireframe*, the object will only ever be drawn as a bounding box or a wireframe.
3. *Solid*. Draws the object's faces as a surface.

   With *maximum draw type* set to *bounds*, the object will only ever be drawn as a bounding box, wireframe, or a solid surface.
4. *Textured*. No limit.

   With *maximum draw type* set to *Textured*, the object is allowed to be drawn in the viewoprt with shading, textures, etc.

Most of the time you want it on textured, but it's sometimes useful to e.g. keep a specific object drawn as a wireframe even while in solid view.