# Texture not showing up

Tags: uv, unity

I made a test cube to begin learning how to texture in the BGE. Although the texture shows in texture paint and in the UV editor, my cube is blank when imported into unity as if I hadn't applied anything. My blend is below. Thank you for the help.

http://www.filedropper.com/testtexture

Comment: What does your material setup look like in Blender?

Comment: You probably have to set the texture in the material, having a texture in the UV editor only displays it in the viewport.

Comment: On the following pages there is some detail on various viewing modes and how to add material textures. Although they don't directly answer your question, the setup you need is there in pieces. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18005/cant-see-shading-in-3d-view http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13479/how-to-generate-final-texture-image-for-complete-designed-scene